# Problem with applying Lagrange (mean value theorem) in a proof.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives

Suppose $A \in R^n$, $A$ open, and we have a function $f:A \rightarrow R^m$

Theorem: If $f \in C^1_A$ then $f$ is differentiable in every point of $A$.

where $f \in C^1_A$ if $f_j$ has partial derivatives in A for $j = 1, ..., n$
and if the function that goes from $x \rightarrow \frac{\partial f_j(x)}{\partial x_k}$ is continuous $\forall j = 1, \dots, n$ and $\forall k = 1,...,n$

Take $m = 1$ since a function is differentiable iff every component is differentiable. And take $n= 2$ as a starting case.

Fix $(x_0,y_0) \in A$ and $h = (h_1,h_2)$

I know that if the differential exists then it must satisfy $$f((x_0,y_0)+ (h_1,h_2)) - f(x_0, y_0) - \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)h_1 - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)h_2 = o(||h||)$$

Now I can write the LHS as

$$f(x_0+ h_1,y_0 +h_2)) -f(x_0+h_1,y_0) +f(x_0+h_1,y_0)- f(x_0, y_0) - \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)h_1 - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)h_2 $$

and noticing that by Langrage I have $$f(x_0+h_1,y_0+h_2) - f(x_0+h,y_0) -\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)h_2 = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0+h_1,y_0+\theta_1 h_2)h_2$$

where $0< \theta_1 <1$

Except I can't see how Lagrange was applied I have only done lagrange in one dimension, and where does the $\theta$ come up?

Could someone clarify this step to me?

Comment: I do not understand the question. What is $C^1_A$, if not the set of continuous and continuously differentiable functions on $A$? If it's that, than the answer to your question is 'yes, by definition'

Comment: @Thomas Sorry I will define C^1_A, anyhow my question is only on the application of the mean value theorem in the last latex lines.